# how to find a bean defined in spring when beans are defined across multiple xml files

Tags: spring

I have inherited a project containing multiple jars containing multiple xml files defining spring beans.
So my question is how do I find where is the actual bean defined ?
Ex ::

```
<bean id="messageDaoBean" class="com.abc.xyz.dao.MyDAOImpl" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"/>
</bean>
```

Now where do I find the definition of "factory" ?
There are no "imports' defined in the xml - so I dont have clues of which XML files to look up

I dont want to do a search using editplus or "find" etc ( which I dont know ) - but will ask a separate question about
so any logical way of identifying where the bean is defined ?
Thanks

Comment: Your remark about EditPlus and `find` seems to imply you're not using an IDE for development; Eclipse-based [STS](https://spring.io/tools/sts) offers everything a Spring developer would need, including beans graphs and global [Quick Search](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/eclipse-quick-search).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in functionality which will give you the name of the spring xml you are looking for. Also (for the sake of completeness) it does not necessarily have to be an xml file. Spring also supports Java-based configuration (classes which are annotation with [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)).

The easiest way would indeed be making a fulltext search in all *.spring.xml in your project.

Or you could look in your dao what the type of your factory is and search for the interface or implementation. Normally there aren't so many matching classes, so you might identify the module you are looking for also this way.